# How to do exception handling for undefined local variables?

Tags: ruby

In the below code how can I do exceptional handling for undefined local variables and run the next line of code.if we observe line 5 "e" has no value .so in my case where there are undefined  local variables how can I handle them and run the lines 7 and 8

```
a=10
b=5
c= a+b
puts c
d = a+e 
puts d 
K = 2+b 
puts k
```

Expected output

```
15
7
```

Comment: What is the usecase you're trying to solve? What point would recoverability have? This is a development-time error.

Comment: Was the use of capital `K` on line 7 vs lower case on line 8 intentional, or additional sloppiness?

Comment: actually its not capital "k" its typo error by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

```
d = a + e rescue nil
```

which would catch the exception and assigns `d = nil`.

Or

```
begin
  d = a + e 
rescue 
end
```

Which only catches the exception and does nothing else because of the empty rescue block.

But I would consider this a bad practice. Because apart from in the console you should never run into this issue in real-life. This error is trivial and should be noticed and fixed before the app gets into production.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the variable is defined
**** Corrected to match OP

```
a=10
b=5
c= a+b
puts c
if defined?(e)
    d = a+e
    puts d
end
K = 2+b 
if defined?(k)
    puts k
end
```

Comment: This is hand coded   I  need in a exception handling way so let us assume if we have more number of undefined local variables how to handle it. Everytime we can't use "defined?" Right?

Comment: Why would you want a boat load of undefined variables in your code? Its bad practice and Perl and PHP are the only ones that you can really sneak by undefined's.

Comment: Note that the original had a capital `K` for the assignment.  You "fixed" it, but there's no way for us to know whether that was a typo or meant as another undefined variable situation.

Comment: @pjs agreed, but when I was giving the desired output, I had to make that correction.

Comment: @BasaSairam if it was intentional then you have to accommodate for the line after also

Comment: Beware that this solution has one notable potential gotcha in that a variable can be defined as ```nil``` in which case you will still end up with an error.  Much better to use proper Exception Handling, specifically using ```rescue```

Answer (score 0):

Undefined variables raise the NameError to rescue from this Error follow the below code

```
a=10
b=5
begin
  c= a+b
  K = 2+b 
  d = a+e 
rescue NameError
end
puts "#{c} \n #{k}"
```